# Imagem desalinhada ao diminuir largura da pagina

Tags: html, css, html5, css3, bootstrap-3

Assim está a resolução da minha imagem na largura normal da pagina

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas ao diminuir a largura da pagina a imagem fica assim.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gostaria que a imagem ficasse com o  mesmo tamanho da imagem 1 pequena

HTML

```
 <div class="col-6 col-md-4">
            <img src="imagens/eccomerce.JPG" alt="principal" id="imagem_principal">
        </div>
```

CSS

```
#imagem_principal{
            width: 92%;
            height: 240px;
        }
```

Comment: Tira o `height`.

Comment: tirei mas continuou o mesmo erro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aparentemente seu CSS não esta sendo aplicado na imagem. No html que passou esta sendo usado uma `ID #imagem_principal` e o CSS esta em uma `CLASS .imagem_principal.`

Como está usando bootstrap voce pode adicionar uma `class ="img-responsive"` que talvez funcione ou se preferir, troque seu html por `class="imagem_principal"` e seu css

```
.imagem_principal{
height: auto;
max-width: 100%;
}
```

Outro problema que acontece é que quando sua tela fica menor, seu html (bootstrap) está ficando com largura total da página, o padrão xs-12. Para isso adicione uma uma tag -xs para controlar a largura da tela em resoluções menores, isso vai evitar que o layout quebre em varias linhas e sua imagem ocupe 100% da tela..

`<div class="col-6 col-md-4 col-xs-4">`

Comment: obrigado pela observação,mas continuou o mesmo erro, ao diminuir a largura da pagina a imagem se destorce ela fica maior

Comment: Alterei minha resposta com uma observação sobre html. O grid esta ficando com largura total da página em telas menores, por isso a imagem fica grande, pois ela ocupa 100% da tela. O que precisa ser feito é adicionar ao HTML opções do bootstrap para controlar o tamanho dos blocos em -XS

Comment: era isso mesmo Maurício Obrigado